# Why are the links in my WordPress site not working after it was migrated to new server and SSL was implemented?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My client's WordPress site was migrated to a new server and SSL was implemented, i.e. https is now on the URL. But now the internal links are not working. I am getting the page not found error message with *Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at shop.ryokudo.asia Port 443*

On Settings > General, the Wordpress and Site Address URL's http was replaced with https. The Settings > Permalink has the https on URL addresses.

The Settings > Permalink lower part reads:
*If your .htaccess file were writable, we could do this automatically, but it isn’t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in your .htaccess file. Click in the field and press CTRL + a to select all.*

Below it is the code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: You did manually paste that code into the .htaccess as the message asked you to, correct?

Comment: Try deleting your .htaccess file (save it in case you need to put it back) and then go to settings>permalinks and save the permalinks.

Comment: I don't have FTP  access yet to the server. As soon as the administrator provides me the access, I'll try out the suggestions. Thanks

Comment: I'm now able to access using winscp. I've updated the .htaccess locally and transferred to the root directory. The links are still not working. What do I do next?